# Fixed standard error and t-value in linear mixed regression

Tags: r, regression, correlation, mixed-model, standard-error

I am trying to conduct a linear mixed regression analysis using R. The data comes form an experiment, in which several plates were treated with different sets of parameters (4 independent variable on 2 levels) and the thickness of the plate was measured (dependent variable). We assume, that within one plate, the error of measuring the thickness is normally distributed and baseline thickness changes form plate to plate randomly following another normal distribution (that's why we used a random intercept model).

Here you can see my R code and the summary

[image]
[image]

I have three questions about it:

1. Why do you think the standard error is the same for each parameter and even the interactions?
2. Why are the correlations of fixed effects all 0? Does that mean, there are no interactive mechanisms between different independent variables regarding the dependent variable? Preliminary examination like interaction plots suggested, there would be!
3. Do you think, it is a good idea in this case to use `REML=TRUE`?

---

Here is my script:

```
   > library(lme4)
   Loading required package: Matrix
   > daten = read.csv(file.choose( ))
   > regression = lmer(thickness ~ temp + vel*debulk*press + 
   (1|experimentID),data=daten)
```

---

This is the used data, extracted using dput():

```
structure(list(experimentID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("T0-P0-V0-Dblk0-Aut0", 
"T0-P0-V0-Dblk1-Aut0", "T0-P0-V1-Dblk0-Aut0", "T0-P0-V1-Dblk1-Aut0", 
"T0-P1-V0-Dblk0-Aut0", "T0-P1-V0-Dblk1-Aut0", "T0-P1-V1-Dblk0-Aut0", 
"T0-P1-V1-Dblk1-Aut0", "T1-P0-V0-Dblk0-Aut0", "T1-P0-V0-Dblk1-Aut0", 
"T1-P0-V1-Dblk0-Aut0", "T1-P0-V1-Dblk1-Aut0", "T1-P1-V0-Dbk0-Aut0", 
"T1-P1-V0-Dblk1-Aut0", "T1-P1-V1-Dblk0-Aut0", "T1-P1-V1-Dblk1-Aut0"
), class = "factor"), sampleID = 1:262, temp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), press = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), vel = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), debulk = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), autoc = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), thickness = c(1.07702, 1.047495, 1.123893, 
1.119536, 1.050537, 1.097328, 1.077989, 1.087568, 1.055652, 1.115327, 
1.023584, 1.104926, 1.067504, 1.06059, 1.222235, 1.002262, 1.051035, 
1.049054, 1.027627, 1.009592, 1.041219, 1.03447, 1.064623, 1.089385, 
1.024802, 1.069435, 1.048253, 1.049391, 1.066601, 1.076928, 1.111959, 
1.02404, 1.030396, 1.045843, 1.00651, 1.01876, 1.037581, 1.069811, 
1.027897, 0.970677, 1.032766, 0.945487, 0.93691, 1.070743, 1.054347, 
0.97901, 1.063218, 1.069438, 1.064606, 0.987543, 1.017333, 0.974271, 
0.99741, 0.983667, 1.088415, 1.077781, 1.099183, 0.986252, 1.065333, 
1.012032, 1.064213, 1.088988, 1.014936, 0.969788, 1.021607, 1.053769, 
1.040966, 1.053094, 1.067226, 1.091193, 1.035079, 1.037127, 1.017368, 
1.064897, 0.989977, 1.067276, 1.042505, 1.041075, 1.057803, 1.005051, 
1.077474, 0.980285, 1.004545, 1.190357, 1.016877, 1.056415, 1.054645, 
1.06315, 1.052742, 1.103623, 1.057956, 1.028971, 1.017831, 1.028583, 
1.069429, 1.103255, 1.045937, 1.079669, 1.117909, 1.054178, 1.047078, 
1.066748, 1.008013, 1.11394, 1.056472, 1.103953, 1.065881, 1.068071, 
1.216658, 1.057916, 1.057626, 1.071498, 1.076745, 1.08051, 1.078876, 
1.118028, 1.085433, 1.062912, 1.02401, 1.000374, 0.969011, 1.029201, 
0.996965, 1.030794, 1.027591, 1.03214, 1.003509, 1.016222, 1.006153, 
0.987447, 1.031364, 1.049474, 1.045676, 0.97206, 0.995844, 1.055402, 
1.026004, 1.029693, 1.030481, 0.97344, 0.975202, 1.034312, 1.052701, 
1.100385, 0.877634, 1.011779, 1.125289, 1.051936, 0.998616, 1.068157, 
1.049553, 1.064288, 1.019269, 1.041033, 1.048296, 1.027233, 1.036831, 
1.155743, 1.06798, 0.98814, 1.03454, 1.014615, 1.016581, 1.007299, 
1.028249, 1.039191, 1.010218, 1.020594, 1.031872, 1.035704, 1.07464, 
1.082165, 1.053641, 1.076084, 1.071422, 0.929941, 1.026688, 1.067, 
0.995563, 1.034693, 1.033178, 0.987651, 0.99946, 1.065944, 1.031627, 
1.062923, 1.040896, 1.049118, 1.04562, 1.052548, 1.016264, 1.065543, 
1.109801, 0.926053, 1.061584, 1.027027, 1.112891, 1.002928, 1.033047, 
1.033091, 1.045355, 1.015776, 1.018057, 1.025359, 1.082198, 1.030077, 
1.011728, 1.074537, 1.027585, 1.065915, 1.084378, 1.037126, 1.024253, 
1.097939, 1.021858, 1.008245, 1.014673, 0.992667, 1.070837, 1.053248, 
0.98834, 1.023689, 0.979945, 0.990217, 0.989128, 0.897916, 1.017531, 
1.126699, 1.029981, 1.026108, 1.031332, 1.028007, 0.989532, 1.031705, 
1.044216, 1.033818, 1.071533, 1.02383, 1.029734, 0.965417, 1.08389, 
1.006066, 0.966172, 1.052382, 0.988453, 1.055174, 1.050683, 1.113076, 
1.098728, 1.0062, 1.044764, 1.042976, 0.968749, 1.082216, 1.020449, 
1.024606, 0.958459, 1.060553, 1.048992, 1.076242, 1.001839, 1.074284
)), .Names = c("experimentID", "sampleID", "temp", "press", "vel", 
"debulk", "autoc", "thickness"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-262L))
```

Comment: Please include your R code and possibly (anonymized) data. This reeks of a data/coding mistake. In any case: not normal.

Comment: Sure no problem! I edited the question accordingly. Unfortunately I did not find an option to add the data (140mb csv-file).

Comment: 1. Is "experiment ID" actually a "disc id"? 2. How many measures per disc and is the design balanced (equal no. obs / disc).

Comment: Using `dput()` you can easily provide your data: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html

Comment: experimentID is equal to discID and no the number of measurements per disc varies

Comment: @Stefan I tried to use your advice, but since my input file consists of 2,6Mio lines, I had to reduce the amount of data drastically for this forum...please see above

Comment: @AdamO please see the data above